# ImageView Image doesn't show at first

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, storyboard

I have set image for image view in storyboard and as well as in `viewWillAppear` using:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: String)
```

but when the view controller first appears the image doesn't show. The image appears when the view controller comes second time.

Comment: set the image in main thread.

Comment: Have you use `autolayout` in that viewcontroller ?

Comment: Using nsopertaionqueue?

Comment: Yes I am using `autolayout`

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: Please, show us what you tried so far. And please, take a few minutes to read this: [ask].

Comment: Try set the image in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: viewDidAppear is the best place to do this , try once